# auto regression test tool for web page on window recommendation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-testing, regression-testing

Greeting Community,

My boss is asking me to do manual checking/testing of our intra-net site
The company is very low budgeted and don't want to spend any money.
What would be open-source free regress test tool it can run stand-alone on a window system? The company uses internet explorer plan to standardize on Window.

Our server system is very limited and we have difficult time to allocate disk space even for 100G.

We support 1000+ users.

Would Selenium be a good choice for this task ??

I am new to regress test on webpage so something simple to setup and learn will be very helpful

Thanks.

Comment: This question is asking for opinions which is not allowed here. I would ask this question on the SQA site, http://sqa.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can a combination of those free and open source tools that can run on Windows with Node.js:

- selenium-webdriver,
- mocha,
- chai.js with chai-webdriver.

That's all you need to perform full end-to-end tests. I use this with Internet Explorer, but it works with Chrome and Firefox, too.